# Trying to import csv data into elasticsearch and then visualise it in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to import below csv formatted data into elasticsearch

Below is my `SampleCSV.csv` file

```
Date,Amount,Type,Db/Cr,Desc
4/1/2015,10773,Car M&F,Db,Insurance 
4/1/2015,900,Supporting Item,Db,Wifi Router 
4/1/2015,1000,Car M&F,Db,Fuel 
4/1/2015,500,Car M&F,Db,Stepni Tyre Tube 
4/1/2015,770,FI,Db,FI 
4/1/2015,65,FI,Db,Milk
```

I am using configuration as below:

```
input { 

stdin {
type => "sample"
}
file {
        path => "C:/Users/Deepak/Desktop/SampleCSV.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
    } }
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["Date","Amount","Type","Db/Cr","Desc"]
separator => ","
  }
}
elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "sample"
        workers => 1
    }
  stdout {
debug=>true
}
}
```

I am executing  below command

```
C:\MyDrive\Apps\logstash-2.0.0\bin>logstash agent -f C:\MyDrive\Apps\logstash-2.
0.0\bin\MyLogsConfig.conf
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
Default settings used: Filter workers: 2
Logstash startup completed
```

Now my problem is that when I am looking in kibana about "sample" related index I am not getting any data at all.It looks no data imported into elastic search thus kibana is not getting not getting any thing.

Do you know the reason why??

Comment: What happens if you add `sincedb_path => null` in the `file` input config?

Answer (score 0):

Several things to take into account. You can split debugging your problem in two parts:

- First you want to make sure that logstash is picking up the file contents as you would expect it to. For that you can remove/comment the elasticsearch output. Restart logstash and add a new line of data to your SampleCSV.csv file (don't forget the newcline/CR at the end of the new line otherwise it wount be picked up). If logstash picks up the new line it should appear in your console output (because you added the stdout output filter). Don't forget that the file input remebers where it last read from a logfile and continues reading from that position (it stores this index in a special file called since_db). start_position => "beginning" only works for the first time you start logstash, on subsequent runs it will start reading from it last ended meaning you won't see any new lines in your console unless you a.) add new lines to your files or b.) manually delete the since_db file (sincedb_path => null is not working under windows, at least when I last tried).
- As soon as you get that working you can start looking at the elasticsearch/kibana side of things. When looking at your config, I'd suggest you stick with the default index name pattern (logstash-XXX where XXX is something like date created, notice: DON'T USE UPPERCASE LETTERS in your index name or elasticsearch will refuse your data). You should use the default pattern because asfaik the special logstash index-mapping (e.g. raw fields,...) is registered for that name pattern only. If you change you'd have to change the mapping too.

The ELK stack is a bit confusing in the beginning but don't hesitate to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks Markus , I will try these and let you know soon